# typedef for C complex type results in compilation error on IAR compiler, but works on GCC and ARMCC

Tags: c, iar, complex.h

I have some C code for an ARM-based microcontroller that already compiles with GCC and the ARM compiler. However, when compiling with IAR V8.42.1, there is a problem with the following

```
typedef float _Complex f_complex;
```

The error message is

```
expected a ";"
```

and the caret is pointing at the "f" in `f_complex`;

I have read up on using complex types in C and such a `typedef` seems to be quite typical. I also checked the IAR compiler manual and C99 is the default C standard, which means that `complex.h` should work right out of the box. None of the compiler flags listed in the manual seem like they could affect this, except for `--c89`, but that's not the default in any case and I am using the compiler with its default settings -- the `CFLAGS` var in my `Makefile` is empty.

It is interesting that if I modify the original `typedef` as follows

```
typedef _Fcomplex f_complex;
```

where `_Fcomplex` is `typedef`ed in `complex.h` as

```
typedef float       _Complex _Fcomplex;
```

it compiles just fine. While it is nice that this version works, the header `typedef` is identical to the one above, aside from the type name.

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I follow: are you saying that you are compiling with the `--c89` flag, and that that flag specifies C89 mode?  I'm not sure why otherwise you would have brought the flag up, but compiling in C89 mode would be an excellent reason for the compiler to fail to recognize `_Complex` as a keyword.

Comment: Accepting ` --c99` switch or defaulting to “using” C 1999 is not the same as asserting a compiler fully conforms to C 1999. Quite likely IAR simply uses the switches to select between various rules or features of the different standards but does not fully conform.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What I meant to say is that I went through the list of compiler flags and the only one that looked like it could cause that specific problem is `--c89`, which I am not using.

Comment: IAR is not 100 conforming. You will need plenty #ifdef`s. BTW I have stopped using IAR 2 y ago. Had enough of it

Comment: A simpler thing to try would be to just write `_Complex f_complex;` and see if you can get it to compile.  I'd also check the IAR manual to see if it mentions complex support.

Comment: @DavidGrayson manal does not know anything about the _Complex

Comment: @EricPostpischil There doesn't appear to be a `--c99` flag, since that is the default. But both you and 0________ point out that IAR doesn't conform, which is the likely cause of my problem then.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Actually, I searched it for 'complex' and got a small number of hits, all unrelated.

Comment: @DavidGrayson `_Complex f_complex;` is an error, the keyword can only be used to modify `float`, `double` or `long double`

Comment: Does `typedef _Complex float f_complex;` work?

Comment: @KamilCuk No, it results in an `explicit type is missing` error.

Comment: Also the complex number library is an optional feature of C. Compilers need not support it. You can check like this: `#if __STDC_NO_COMPLEX__==1 #error Not supported" #endif`.

Comment: @Lundin, complex types are optional in C11 and later, but the OP seems to be asking about C99, and as far as I can tell, they were not optional in that version of the language.